# How prime numbers are related to special functions?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, special-functions, riemann-zeta, polylogarithm

We know that the [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) is defined as

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s},$$

for all $\Re(s)>1$.

Because of [Euler product formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Euler_product_formula) we also know that

$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}},$$
for all $\Re(s)>1.$

There are a lot of functions related to Riemann zeta function. For example

- $\zeta(s)=\zeta(s,1)$ where $\zeta(s,q)$ is the [Hurwitz zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function).
- $\zeta(s)=\operatorname{Li}_s(1)$, where $\operatorname{Li}_s(z)$ is the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).
- $\zeta(s)=(1-2^{-s})^{-1}\chi_s(1)$, where $\chi_s(z)$ [Legendre chi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_chi_function)
- $\zeta(s)=\Phi (1,s,1)$, where $\Phi(z, s, \alpha)$ is the [Lerch zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function)
- $ \zeta(s) = (1-2^{1-s})^{-1}\eta(s)$, where $\eta(s)$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function)
- $\dots$ and there are lot of other related functions such as [multiple zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function), [Barnes zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_zeta_function), the [Clausen function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function), etc.

**Question.** Are there Euler product formula type statements to other special functions?

Comment: You have linked to the Wikipedia pages on those functions. Were any Euler products given on those pages? If not, then that's very strong evidence that there are no Euler products.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Or they are just not that well-known to be there.

Comment: Well, the functions are well-known, and well-studied, so I figure if they have Euler products then it's well-known that they do.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You could find some related thing [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.2246.pdf).

Comment: I see a lot of products there, but none over primes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No. Not over primes, but over *relatively primes*.

Answer (score 1):

The online L-functions and modular forms database ([lmfdb.org](http://www.lmfdb.org/)) provides detailed information on a very large number of special functions and provides a functional equation and Euler product form for each of them.

Comment: I just don't understand how to navigate across that webpage, it is so confusing!